# Should the [triangle-generation] tag be removed, as it has three bad sides?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

[triangle-generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triangle-generation) attracts very different questions, mostly of low quality.

Some talk about OpenGL, some talk about putting triangles as markers into plots, others about drawing ASCII art triangles, then there's the occasional basic math question. I would have expected some vertex shader discussions, too.

I recommend removal of the tag, since it bears little benefit and is what pops up when askers type in "triangle" in the tag field -- and usually, it would be more helpful if they were discouraged to use a tag that "sounds similar" to their problem, and used one that covers the *topic* better, e.g. [computational-geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computational-geometry).

So:

1. tag cannot stand alone and contains little information about the problem
2. tag fits into very disparate fields, making it bad to use as search criterion
3. tag existence leads to badly tagged questions rather than encouraging users to find tags that categorize their question well

Comment: Surely removing it would simply mean the bad questions weren't as well tagged, and harder to find?

Comment: @Tim: The idea is that the existence of the tag leads to the opportunity to tag badly; since there's no "good way to tag with [tag:triangle-generation]", it's inherently a *bad* tag.

Comment: Given that 1.There are only 19 questions 2.There is no tag summary 3.It requires another tag and cannot stand alone, burning that tag sounds good, bud there is a problem .... *There is no PUN in the request title!!*

Comment: @MarcusMüller fair enough - although of those 19 questions only 2 are negatively scored. I can still see how it would be a bad tag.

Comment: @BhargavRao should I really fix that?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Absolutely! Puns in the title are like the *go ahead* signal to start burning the tag.

Comment: @BhargavRao obviously, you're very serious, and hence, you must be right. Fixed!

Comment: Thanks for that! I have gone ahead and voted to close a few of the bad questions pushing them to the review queue. I have also started to re-tag them. Given a few handful questions, it should not take long

Comment: @MarcusMüller The tag has been ***BURNINATED***

Comment: @BhargavRao: you are a real master of the fire, and have proven your worth in the face of the triangle, the most simple area-carrying polygon there is.

Comment: @MarcusMüller If there was any tag to be burninated which had a ring like name, then would the burninator be called the *ring master of fire*?

Comment: @BhargavRao great. Now I have to search SO tags for such elements, just so we can find out by trying.

Comment: @BhargavRao: [tag:cycle-sort] might be one for you.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Nope. That sounds like a good tag actually. Though there are less questions.

Comment: @BhargavRao yeah, you're right about the tag quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag [triangle-generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triangle-generation) is quite ambiguous and warranted burnination. It had no tag summary initially. The tag  had a lot of bad questions. Most of them were "gimmetehcodez" questions that were posted 4 to 5 years ago. Many were resource requests. It also included a [self-immolation](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2985580/21) attempt. All these issues have been taken care of. Few of the questions which were good have been re-tagged to more relevant tags.

*There are no more questions with this tag*

[image: Saving the image here to post after the tag has disappeared]

Comment: Gotta love that dragon!